# can we animate visibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(".leftNav").animate({"visibility": "visible"}, 200);
```

I tried it and it doesn't work and I can't use .show()

If I should be using `.show()` tho, another solution which may solve my issue is rather in regards of css and the question it'd be:

Can i `position: fixed` an element without to use display:block? Because i'd need `display:none` in order to use show()

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031927/visibility-option-in-jquery

Comment: @j08691 - actually found my answer from that post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually found my own answer with the correct syntax by following another post on stack:
[Fading visibility of element using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031927/visibility-option-in-jquery)

```
$('.element').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
```

Thanks for your answers tho.

Answer (score 4):

You could set your element to have `opacity:0` and animate it like:

```
$(".leftNav").animate({"opacity": 1}, 200);
// or (thanks elclanrs)
$(".leftNav").fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

Alternatively, you can set it to `display:none` and use

```
$(".leftNav").fadeIn(200);
```

Without seeing your HTML / CSS it is difficult to provide more accurate advice.

Comment: Or `opacity:0` and `$(".leftNav").fadeTo('fast', 1)`

Comment: hi thanks Michael. I can't use 'display:none' as per my question unfortunately

Comment: @rob.m Glad to help :) If you want your 'invisible' element to continue be layed out but just not visible, then `display:none` isn't useful here, agreed.

Comment: yep, thanks, got the full syntax from the post ink on stack linked above by the other user. So this will be really: $('.leftNav').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});

Comment: But `opacity: 0` won't work in IE so you end up doing `visibility: hidden` and `$el.fadeTo(0,0); $el.css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast',1)`

Comment: yes i actually thought of IE, i thougth via jquery opacity would work. I will use fade instead. Thanks!