# How to change visibility of a div slidely with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A div is required to be hidden with the following style:

```
.result-container
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I would like to show this div by applying a sliding down animation.

`$(".result-container").slideDown("slow");` would work if the div had `display: none;`, but it doesn't.

How do I have `.slideDown()` toggle the `visibility`property instead of `display`?

Comment: What do you mean by "slidely"?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve and 'Slidely' is not a word.

Comment: That's obvious, he wants to get a "slideDown" effect, not a "fadeIn" effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031927/fading-visibility-of-element-using-jquery

Comment: You could use `hide()` to initially hide it such as `$(".result-container").hide().slideDown("slow");`.  If this happens 'onload', this might cause a bit of a jump when the page and would be better if you used CSS to hide the div.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/tleish/3ZL9j/

Comment: Some cooperation is needed if u want help man...

Comment: thank you all for helping me. (sorry about language difficulties :D )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the container to be visible and undisplayed and then apply `.slideDown()`.

```
$button = $('.button');
$container = $('.container');

$button.click( function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $container
    .css({
      visibility: 'visible',
      display: 'none'
    })
    .slideDown();
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/sefor/1/edit