# Make div visible by fading it in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the page loads, I have hidden a div using

```
#hidDiv{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I use jQuery to make it visible.

```
$('#hidDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

My question is how do I make it fade in gently instead of appearing quickly?

Note: It's important that `visibility: hidden;` should be maintained. E.g. can not use `hide();` instead of `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fading visibility of element using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031927/fading-visibility-of-element-using-jquery)

Comment: @sdcr: thanks I did not come across that while googling. Perhaps coz I wasn't aware of how to do the `animate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use jQuery [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

```
 $('div').fadeIn();
```

Otherwise, if `visibility` must be maintained, do

```
$('div').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
```

```js
$('div').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
```

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

See [Want to use jquery fade in effects, but want to use visibility:hidden initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817551/want-to-use-jquery-fade-in-effects-but-want-to-use-visibilityhidden-initially)

Comment: Looks good. thanks. I guess `animate()` is what I was looking for . :)

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use JQuery,

html:

```
<div id="theElement" class="hide"></div>
```

css:

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

*`1s` is the number of seconds to fade for. Make sure you change all of them.

You can then just change the class with javascript:

```
document.getElementById('theElement').className = 'show'; // Fade in
document.getElementById('theElement').className = 'hide'; // Fade out
```

### More Reading:

- [Simple documentation from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)
- [More thorough documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)
- [Compatibility info from caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Comment: Should be: 
`document.getElementById("theElement").className = "show"; 
document.getElementById("theElement").className = "hide";`
since `theElement` is an id

Comment: Good catch—I must have been writing fast. Thanks @toing_toing

Answer (score 1):

As AmmarCSE has stated, if you are using jQuery you can use `$("div").fadeIn();` for more control you can also set a timeframe using fadeIn's first argument. ie

`$("div").fadeIn("slow");`.

This first argument can be one of the built in time values of "fast" or "slow" etc or it can be a time in milliseconds ie

`$("div").fadeIn(1000);`

The function also has a callback in case you want to do something once the element has finished fading in. It can be used like so...

```
$("div").fadeIn("slow",function(){
  console.log("finished fading in");
});
```

You can also use fadeOut() in the same manner to fade the div back out... `$("div").fadeOut("slow");`

The docs on fadeIn() can be found here -> http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Another option would be to use jQuery's animate() function on the elements opacity. Ie.

```
$("div").animate({
  opacity:0
},"slow");
```

This is useful if you also want to animate other properties of the element at the same time. ie.

```
$("div").animate({
  opacity:0,
  left:200
},"slow");
```

The docs for animate() can be found here -> http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Another option would to use css transitions like so...

```
div {
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition:opacity:1s;
}
div.fadeIn {
    opacity:1;
}
```

And then use jquery to add or remove the fadeIn class to trigger the fading ie.

```
$("body").on("click",function(){
  $("div").toggleClass("fadeIn");
});
```

This will fade the div in or out on click of the body.

More info on transitions here -> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

You could also use css animations but I wont go into that here. Hope the extra info helps someone.